# How to select an element using the name and value attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an element created dynamically by a razor syntax.I want to select this element from its `name` and also `value` attributes. My element is:

```
<input type="radio" name="4501_LS" value="1" class="icheck " data-radio="iradio_line-blue" data-label="Var" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
```

actually I tried the code below,

```
$(('icheck[name=4504_LS]').attr('value') = '1')
```

but it is probably wrong or unadequate. What am I mising?

Comment: `icheck` would select an element with that _tag/element name_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `name` and `value`, you can just use two attribute selectors:

```
$('[name="4501_LS"][value="1"]')
```

I would qualify that, as you tried to. You were using a class, so you need to put the `.` there to make it a class selector:

```
$('.icheck[name="4501_LS"][value="1"]')
```

---

Just a word of warning: The `value` *attribute* doesn't change when you change the value of an input; the `value` *attribute* defines the *default value* of an input, which is (of course) its initial value. I figure you're probably not changing the values of those inputs, since they're radio buttons, but I'm just flagging it up for lurkers. When the value of an input is changed (e.g., `input.value = x;` or `$(/*...*/).val(x);` or the user changes it if it's a text input or similar), no attribute is changed at all. To change the `value` attribute, you have to set the `defaultValue` property (or set the attribute via the DOM's `setAttribute` or jQuery's `attr`).